# Logarithm in functional language with addition and multiplication only

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, logarithm

While learning for an exam, I've just found the following task in an exercise:

*Write a function that gives the integer logarithm to base 2 (rounded up) while only using multiplication and addition.*

I tried, immediately, but couldn't come to any solution. I thought that would be an easy task but I could only find a solution when using integer division (e.g. in Haskell):

```
log2 :: Int -> Int
log2 1 = 0
log2 2 = 1
log2 x = 1 + log2 (x `div` 2)
```

Is this task possible with multiplication only at all? Using multiplication on the left side (pattern) always results in compiler errors. And using it on the right side, how can I trace the solution back to lower numbers?

Comment: You can do it with addition, multiplication, and `<=`. Also, your case for 2 is redundant, in that example.

Comment: Division IS multiplication

Comment: But I have to use `Int`s, no fractions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> And using it on the right side, how can I trace the solution back to lower numbers?

Recursion. Since it's easier to compute the floor, we use the fact that

```
ceiling (log_2 n) == floor (log_2 (2*n-1))
```

as can easily be seen. Then to find the logarithm to the base `b`, we compute the logarithm to base `b²` and adjust:

```
log2 :: Int -> Int
log2 1 = 0
log2 2 = 1
log2 n
    | n < 1     = error "Argument of logarithm must be positive"
    | otherwise = fst $ doLog 2 1
      where
        m = 2*n-1
        doLog base acc
            | base*acc > m = (0, acc)
            | otherwise = case doLog (base*base) acc of
                            (e, a) | base*a > m -> (2*e, a)
                                   | otherwise  -> (2*e+1,a*base)
```

A simpler algorithm that needs more steps would be to simply iterate, multiplying with 2 in each step, and count, until the argument value is reached or surpassed:

```
log2 :: Int -> Int
log2 n
    | n < 1     = error "agument of logarithm must be positive"
    | otherwise = go 0 1
      where
        go exponent prod
            | prod < n  = go (exponent + 1) (2*prod)
            | otherwise = exponent
```

Comment: `doLog :: (Num a) => a -> a -> (a, a)` or something like that. Shouldn't you project it in the `log2 n | otherwise` case? ;)

Comment: Ah, forgot the `fst`, thanks. Due to the top-level signature, it's `doLog :: Int -> Int -> (Int,Int)`, but of course it would also work polymorphically.

Comment: Of course. That would require you to pass `m` explicitly, though.

Comment: I don't see that. Why would one need to pass `m`?

Comment: Thank you very much! Obviously, this works exactly as intended. But isn't there a way to simplify this?

Comment: @DanielFischer: in the `where` clause, `m :: Int` because `n :: Int`. In the first guard of `doLog`, `base, acc :: Int` because `m :: Int`.

Comment: @Tinctorius And if `n :: t` for some `(Ord t, Num t)`, then `m :: t` and `base, acc :: t`. If `log2` is called at type `a -> r`, then `doLog` inherits type `a -> a -> (b, a)` from the guards, doesn't need any passing of `m`.

Comment: @MarcoW. It is already rather simple, I think. Of course you can have a simpler and slower algorithm. That's no problem, I will add one.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
log2 n = length (takeWhile (<n) (iterate (*2) 1))
```

?

I assume you can use functions from the Prelude (like `error`, `fst` and the comparison operators). If that's not allowed on the exam, you could theoretically use the definitions of `length`, `takeWhile` and `iterate` and end up with something relatively close (in spirit, probably not in the letter!) to Daniel's answer.

Comment: Thank you for this super-short alternative!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use series expansion to approximate the log function. Especially [Taylor’s ones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series).

Comment: Thank you! I guess nothing of that complexity is needed, just some basic list operations.